# Making occurrence of object in array a property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add a new property to multiple objects in a array that counts its occurrence. The current function **can** delete duplicated objects but **cannot** count how many times it is repeated.

```
const artists = [
    { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', 'id': 1 },
    { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', 'id': 2 },
    { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', 'id': 3 },
    { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', 'id': 1 },
    { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', 'id': 3 },
    { name: 'John',   age: '18', 'id': 4 },
    { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', 'id': 2 },
    { name: 'Tenner', age: '30', 'id': 5 },
    { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', 'id': 3 },
]

const countOccurrence = (arr) => {
    let uniqueArray = []

    uniqueArray = arr.filter(item => {
        item['occurrence'] = ++item['occurrence'] || 1
        if (!uniqueArray.includes(item.id)) {
            uniqueArray.push(item.id)
            return true
        }
    })

    return uniqueArray
}

let uniqueArtists = countOccurrence(artists)
console.log(uniqueArtists)
```

I'm getting:

```
[
  { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', id: 1, occurrence: 1 },
  { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', id: 2, occurrence: 1 },
  { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3, occurrence: 1 },
  { name: 'John',   age: '18', id: 4, occurrence: 1 },
  { name: 'Tenner', age: '30', id: 5, occurrence: 1 }
]
```

I'm trying to get:

```
[
  { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', id: 1, occurrence: 2 },
  { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', id: 2, occurrence: 2 },
  { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3, occurrence: 3 },
  { name: 'John',   age: '18', id: 4, occurrence: 1 },
  { name: 'Tenner', age: '30', id: 5, occurrence: 1 }
]
```

The order does not matter, I'm just trying to get the right occurrence values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a hash table and increment the occurence for each grouped worker.

This approach does not mutate the original data.

```js
const
    workers = [{ name: 'Paul',   age: '18', id: 1 }, { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', id: 2 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3 }, { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', id: 1 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3 }, { name: 'John',   age: '18', id: 4 }, { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', id: 2 }, { name: 'Tenner', age: '30', id: 5 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3 }],
    countOccurrence = (arr) => {
        let uniqueArray = [],
            hashTable = {}

        arr.forEach(item => {
            if (!hashTable[item.id]) {
                uniqueArray.push(hashTable[item.id] = { ...item, occurrence: 0 });
            }
            hashTable[item.id].occurrence++;
        });

        return uniqueArray;
    },
    uniqueArtists = countOccurrence(workers);

console.log(uniqueArtists);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly different approach by using an object and getting the values as return  array.

```js
const
    workers = [{ name: 'Paul',   age: '18', id: 1 }, { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', id: 2 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3 }, { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', id: 1 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3 }, { name: 'John',   age: '18', id: 4 }, { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', id: 2 }, { name: 'Tenner', age: '30', id: 5 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', id: 3 }],
    countOccurrence = (arr) => {
        let hashTable = {}

        arr.forEach(item => {
            if (!hashTable[item.id]) {
                hashTable[item.id] = { ...item, occurrence: 0 };
            }
            hashTable[item.id].occurrence++;
        });

        return Object.values(hashTable);
    },
    uniqueArtists = countOccurrence(workers);

console.log(uniqueArtists);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: In the first approach, how occurrences in the uniqueArray are getting updated since the code seems to update (with ++) only the occurrences in the hashTable?

Comment: `uniqueArray.push(hashTable[item.id] = { ...item, occurrence: 0 });` acts in two ways, first it assigns a new object to the hash table *and* it puishes this object to `uniqueArray`. a later increment of `occurence` is made by gettign the object from the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that while you update each item in your filter, you're updating only the current iterated value, and then including it in the output (by returning `true` to `filter`) only in the case that you haven't already seen its `id`.  So as you go through, you update the `occurrence` of each one to `1`, but then ignore the duplicates.  You need to somehow track these by `id`.

You can do this in a single `reduce` call, wrapped in `Object .values`, like this:

```js
const countOccurrences = xs => Object .values (xs .reduce ((
  a, x, _i , _arr, // last two unused 
  {occurrences, ...rest} = x .id in a ? a [x .id] : {...x, occurrences: 0}
) => ({
  ... a,
  [x .id] : {...rest, occurrences: occurrences + 1}
}), {}))

const workers = [ { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', 'id': 1 }, { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', 'id': 2 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', 'id': 3 }, { name: 'Paul',   age: '18', 'id': 1 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', 'id': 3 }, { name: 'John',   age: '18', 'id': 4 },     { name: 'Joseph', age: '21', 'id': 2 }, { name: 'Tenner', age: '30', 'id': 5 }, { name: 'Maggie', age: '20', 'id': 3 } ]

console .log (
  countOccurrences (workers)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top:0}
```

Note that this does not mutate your original data.

It also does not mutate the accumulator used in the `reduce` call or its properties.  That can occasionally be a performance problem.  If your data sets are large or if you're doing this often, you might want to change from this style of immutable accumulator objects to one that mutates the internal accumulator and its values as you go.  Rich Snapp has an [excellent article](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) describing the reasons for this.  But if this performance is acceptable, then I wouldn't bother, as I find this cleaner.